# the det of identity replacing column

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in{\mathbb{R}}^{n\times n}$, $b\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be given, where $A$ is nonsingular and $Ax=b$ holds. Let $X_{j}$ be the matrix obtained from the $n\times n$ identity matrix by replacing the $j$th column with the vector $x$.
      (a) What is det($X_{j}$)
(b)what is $AX_{j}$

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Cramer.27s_rule

Comment: $det(X_j)$ equals to the jth element of $x$, for the definition of det().